# Should we avoid rhetorical questions in answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858301/why-is-there-such-a-big-difference-on-time-between-first-nanotime-call-and-the/31858446#31858446) was flagged by users that thought I'm *asking OP for clarification*.

[image]

However, this is **not** the case. If you read my answer, you can easily understand that these questions actually helped OP understanding the difference times between sequence calls for the method.

Users who flagged the answer didn't note that these questions are *not* meant to be answered, and OP clearly understood that (also I don't really think that in that context someone really expected an answer from OP).

Should I avoid "questions" that are not actually need to be answered? I think the questions *did* help OP to understand difference between time execution, I wasn't actually asking them to clarify whether or they considered the JVM warming up for example.

Please let me know why should we avoid "questions" when trying to explain something to OP.

Please note that I'm **not asking to undelete my answer**, I just need to know if it's forbidden to ask rhetorical questions for explanation purposes.

Comment: I'd remove that last "forbidden" bit as that it a complete 180 from what the question is really about (if it is a good idea or not).

Comment: Almost a bit funny, that such an **answer** gets deleted, but when I see other answers with only 1 sentence which is an arbitrary assumption or suggestion it doesn't get deleted with the reason: "The user *tries* to answer the question".

Comment: Agreed with above. I've seen (*and*) flagged answers containing far less information only to be rejected by points mongering (*I won't type the word I really want to use*) people, it absolutely baffles me. I also seen answers given by higher rep'd members that do ask a rhetorical question inside there, given there is "some code". At least that qualifies as a partial answer which I find perfectly acceptable.

Comment: _I'm not asking to undelete my answer_ - Why not? I don't have the rep to see it but it sounds like your answer was OK.

Comment: @BSMP I think OP wrote that, so that the meta question here itself is about: *"Should we avoid rhetorical questions in answers?"* (, ... and maybe only secondary then to undelete the answer, if it was some kind of misunderstanding or mistake)

Comment: Suggestion: Either a paste of the question or a screenshot should be included here, so that lower rep members can see the whole picture ;-)

Comment: Nothing wrong with that answer, but phrasing those questions as sentences could be a solution. For example, instead of "Did you consider the JVM warming up?", it could be "Consider the JVM warming up." Although you really shouldn't need to do this in the first place.

Comment: is it worth asking the mod who deleted it? See what the reasoning for the deletion was?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with that answer. It should be undeleted.

Comment: Is it seriously this easy for an answer like this to get deleted? It angers me a little when I see stuff like this happen on SO.

Comment: Why did a moderator delete the answer? This is getting worse and worse.

Comment: I... wouldn't have deleted that, and I sure as heck would undelete it in a heartbeat. But I'm going to wait for Martijn to respond before I do anything...

Comment: This community is becoming increasingly pedantic in a very peculiar, StackOverflow-y way. And it's headed to pure moronic whim.

Comment: Don't try to defeat the StackOverflow thought police. You'll never win. Just carry on trying to help the users, and ignore the people trying to stop you.

Comment: Oof. My drink tastes an awful lot like seawater today...

Comment: It would've been hilarious if the title to the question ended without a question mark. :)

Comment: I wonder how many people on SO are actually bots. Particularly moderators.

Comment: Just to be precise, these questions are not "rhetorical questions", which means something specific.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

We shouldn't cater for the lowest common denominator (people who don't speak English natively / don't understand rhetorical questions / don't get sarcasm) when answering. Your answer was fine.

To elaborate, based on comments: everyone has their own writing style. If a couple of relevant questions can make the reader think about a subject, those questions have their place in an answer. Of course we should strive to make answers as readable as possible, but a question in an answer does not by definition make that a bad answer.

Comment: The SO users that posted the what-the-heck comments are from the USA and Ireland.

Comment: @Hans so they spotted question marks in an answer at which point they stopped reading and flagged it. They shouldn't. I guess that means they don't understand rhetorical questions.

Comment: @CodeCaster Maybe it was a robot  user or a script which just searches for question marks in answers and doesn't understand  rhetorical questions :]

Comment: The mission statement for SO event states: `Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers`.

Comment: @HansPassant Where they are from is irrelevant. Limited comprehension from any location is not our problem or the site's focus.

Comment: @CodeCaster, have you considered that I do understand rhetorical questions? What if the questions in the post were not bad because they were questions, but because they contributed nearly nothing towards helping the OP understand the answer to his question? Are spam-bot-like generic question checklists really an answer?

Comment: @Paul we don't go around flagging answers whose writing style we don't like.

Comment: @CodeCaster, it wasn't the style at all but rather the contents. Question form has nothing to do with it. If the post said "Consider other processes on your machine. Consider the JVM warming up. Consider garbage collection.", I would have likewise flagged it.

Comment: @Paul that's exactly what the accepted answer mentions. The question _is_ _"Why does my benchmark show this behavior?"_, which OP answered. Anyway I'm talking about the general issue, not this specific case. The question we're talking about should be closed as a duplicate of a canonical _"How to properly benchmark JITed code?"_ Q&A.

Comment: @CodeCaster, this has nothing to do with JIT compilation. This has to do with lazy class loading/initialization. But that aside, naming a bunch of things with 0 explanation isn't an answer. "bits, bytes, CPU, cache"

Comment: I sort of disagree with @CodeCaster. It's good practice to explain your answer so non-native English speakers understand what's going on; it leads to better discussion. But this shouldn't be taken to mean that all answers are devoid of individual style, and the OP's answer certainly shouldn't have been deleted.

Comment: @CodeCaster I think we're in violent agreement. I agree answers with good content but not-quite-clear English (whether because of style or language barrier) should be accepted. I'm just stating it's often better to spend 30 seconds and write more clearly for non-native speakers.

Comment: This answer lacks rhetorical questions.  Why do you hate human kind?

Comment: IMHO, moderators should tread very carefully when deleting. There is a system in place to assess users' reputation, and voting ensures questions and answers are also rated. If these are too easy to game, try to make it more robust. If they are hard to game, and an answer is reasonably well rated, then it just proves at least some people actually thought it was valuable. It's not a moderator's job to then decide to remove it because *he* doesn't like it. Downvoting it and/or leaving a comment is quite enough.

Answer (score 67):

That depends. What was the intent of the original question? What was the intent of the rhetorical question? Are rhetorical questions inherently helpful or useful? Was it useful in your specific case? Does an answer have to only contain statements? Are you able to phrase an answer in the form of a question?

Comment: Is this answer a joke?

Comment: What is a joke really @toothbrush?

Comment: Perhaps I know, but perhaps I don't?

Comment: Is knowing really that important, or is the journey of discovery the true goal?

Comment: Hmm... Perhaps both?

Comment: Perhaps ... but do you truly need an answer?

Comment: Perhaps we should stop here?

Comment: Do you really want me to answer that?

Comment: You don't want to answer it?

Comment: Will you have a good evening and a good weekend?

Comment: Should the above be flagged as "too chatty" or "not constructive"? Or maybe they should not because they're very funny?

Comment: @MattAllegro shouldn't we flag for deletion all the comments here that aren't rhetorical questions?

Comment: @ChrisSearles: I do have. No question.

Comment: @Bergi Did you mean to put "No question?"?

Answer (score 59):

Yup, my bad. I undeleted it for you.

I was processing about 100 NAA flags and yours looked like a comment to me at the time. I should have taken a little more time there.

Answer (score 26):

We should not avoid rhetorical questions, or question marks in answers.

The value of this site is that askers get answers.  Sometimes the best answer is one that causes the asker to think about a question.  Sometimes the answerer thinks, but is not certain, that he has a good solution.  "Have you considered X? Because ..." is a perfectly valid answer in that case.

A question mark is a communication tool. It should not be treated like a red flag.

Answer (score 13):

> Should we avoid rhetorical questions in answers?

I don't think it necessary to avoid rhetorical questions in answers.

I can see why the questions in your answer can be seen as though you are seeking clarification instead of serving the purpose of answering the OP's question.

They could've been easily phrased as non-questions.

> Many things can affect your calculations.
>
> 1. The other processes on your machines.
> 2. The JVM was warming up.
> 3. The garbage collection.
>
> All these factors and more leads to this behavior.
>
> ...

Answer (score 8):

I'd say there is nothing wrong with your answer.

Rhetorical questions can be effective teaching tools. In the strictest prescriptive English-ness of a great Q&A site *not* using them is probably better English and for some non-native English speakers (and maybe some dialects) the answer *may* not be as clear.

> Many things may affect your calculations. What about other processes?
>   Did you consider the JVM warming up? ...

could be replaced with something more like

> Many things may affect your calculations, i.e. other processes, JVM *"warming up"* ...

I'd argue it is only really a function of form, and the SE sites are meant to be somewhat open and informal. Every enthusiast is here because they enjoy helping. And being over prescriptive on grammar is not the correct direction for reviewers.

Answer (score 8):

I flagged that post as "not an answer".

I did not think you were asking for clarification; I thought you posted a list of (rhetorical) questions, which did not answer the question.

An analogy would be a question on codereview.stackexchange.com "Is this coded well?" and the answer is "Does this follow language/framework conventions? Is there duplicate code? Does this follow the single responsibility principle? What security implications are there?" And left it at that. *It's a **generic checklist** that could be applied to any code review.*

Or if you asked your mechanic about a rattling sound and he "answered", "What about your **tires**? Have you considered the **head gasket cover**? Maybe the **glovebox**?" and proceeded to list every part of the the car, I hope you would not consider that an answer.

If the OP's series of questions would be considered an answer (I say it is not), this post would also be an "answer" to virtually *any* sort of Java performance question ever.

I considered downvoting as simply a low-quality answer, but concluded there really wasn't enough on-topic information to be considered an answer; hence the flag. If -- for example -- you had explained at all why the temperature of the JVM mattered or related to this question, I would have considered this an answer, even though it was mostly incorrect (see the top-voted answer).

It was piece of commentary, not a answer in any sense that I would consider.

---

Rhetorical questions are usually fine, sometimes effective, and occasionally great. But they shouldn't be left as teasers to an answer; there should be enough information in the post to properly answer the question.

---

EDIT: To be clear: the presence of rhetorical questions is a red herring. This post was flagged for its content, not for its style.

Consider the post without questions:

> Consider **other processes** on your machines. Consider the **JVM warming up.** Maybe it was **garbage collection.**

This is likewise commentary or discussion, not an answer.

Comment: Devil's advocate - a generic answer, or an answer that misses the point completely, is still an answer if there isn't any clear evidence that it was simply text that was mistakenly posted via the answer form. Unhelpful, but an answer nonetheless.

Comment: Likewise, voted to close. Not a good answer to my taste.

Comment: @BoltClock, I'm sure he appreciates the advocacy :) I agree generic answers or answers that miss the point can still be answers. I consider this a generic *response* or *commentary*, with no answering going on.

Comment: "any answer that mentions any possible cause is a proper answer" @CodeCaster, I'm starting work on the answer that will answer every question on StackOverflow. I guarantee the solution will be one of the things I list.

Comment: To modify your mechanic metaphor - I'd say the question that was asked was why is there a rattling sound and he actually fixed the problem, but still proceeded to ask vague things like "What about the tires?", without saying how he fixed the problem. Technically this doesn't answer the question of why there was a rattling sound particularly well, but most people just want to get rid of the rattling sound and doesn't care that much about the underlying cause, regardless of the phrasing of the question (although *this* person might've been wondering about the underlying cause, who knows).

Comment: Just to clarify - wanting to get rid of the rattling sound = wanting to be able to run benchmarks without this "strange" behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

- Good answers containing questions (whether it be rhetorical, "Is this what you want?" or whatever else) occasionally get flagged and/or deleted for that reason.
- It takes some manpower to flag and tend to flags.
- It's easy to rephrase your answer to avoid rhetorical questions, as a few of the other answers demonstrate.
- Thus we occasionally lose good content and cause unnecessary work for people, which could easily be avoided (the losing of content could be avoided after the fact, but this also requires some manpower).

So, I'd say avoid it, even if there's nothing, technically speaking, wrong with it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with rhetorical questions is that they can sometimes be misunderstood or misconstrued as being offensive. For the purpose of educating future readers of all cultures, including those in which rhetorical questions are often used only in heated arguments, we should minimise use. The same goes for other offense-laden rhetorics like sarcasm.

Fanciful language and extensive use of rhetorical devices belong better in more casual or exciting media, like films and novels; for educational resources, a factual reporting style with fewer rhetorical devices is often more appropriate. An occasional rhetorical question is generally fine, especially if accompanying text goes on to answer and explain them clearly. In such cases, answers tend to be long and rich in content. Short answers containing rhetorical questions tend to sound condescending.

In other words: while rhetorical questions are fine, too much can be counter-productive. The OP's answer could probably be refined to contain less/none of them.

---

**P/S**: Just to sneak in a rhetorical question: when was the last time you read a Wikipedia article containing a rhetorical question?