# Is a sarcastic answer, a no-answer, still an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, disputed-review-audits

The [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849419/how-to-get-the-count-of-each-individuals-salary):

How to get the count of each individual's salary?

I am using MySQL. There are 2 tables:

```
table1->Emp------columns(ID,name)
table2->Sal------columns(ID,sal,month)
```

Note: there are 2 months or 3 months salary in the table sal.

Write a query to get the employee name and the employee salary (for each employee).

---

Clearly a homework question or similar, with no research effort at all.

The answer I flagged is sarcastic, clever, funny, but it *does not attempt to answer the question*. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether:

```
SELECT all.effort 
  FROM others
     , instantly 
 WHERE homework = 'mine'
```

---

Funny, but clearly not an answer. My flag was disputed, and I guess that is the decision of a higher ranked member. Shouldn't I have flagged it as a no-answer? Should it be disputed? Please explain.

Comment: That could be *an* answer to *a* question. NaA flags are for posts that could not be an answer to any question, such as a question... or "Thanks!"

Comment: `DELETE brain FROM flag_reviewers WHERE reviewer = 'idiot'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Obviously it's not an answer:

> This was posted as an answer, but it **does not attempt to answer the question**. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

The textual representation of that answer is *"We aren't going to do your homework"*, which should be a comment at best.

However, as explained in [A minor change to the description of the "not an answer" flag: "the question" → "a question"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag/286270#286270), you shouldn't use the "Not an answer" flag for it, because it *could be interpreted as an answer* by the mod, who sees such posts without any context. Use a custom flag.

Comment: This is brought up in every single "why was my NaA flag declined" meta post, the fact is that the title says "Not ***an*** answer" and mods treat it as such. If it is ***an*** answer then the flag is incorrect.

Comment: @Tiny I'm not following you. Maybe the mod handling the flag didn't read the SQL itself. The answer as posted is not an answer to the question and should not have been posted as an answer.

Comment: See also: [How do I properly use the “Not an Answer” flag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185074/288751) It doesn't have to answer ***the*** question, it just has to be ***an*** answer to ***a*** question

Comment: As CodeCaster has highlighted, @TinyGiant, the _explanation_ says "does not attempt to answer **the** question". But regardless of the precise wording, garbage answers like this _don't add anything to the site_. In fact, they take away from it. Not deleting crap, allowing the page to clog with non-solutions, is doing it wrong. I don't even think this one requires you to read the programming language.

Comment: @Tiny did you _read_ the answer? It's _"You're lazy"_ in SQL. It is not an attempt to answer the question asked by OP. It is not possible to mold that SQL into a working solution for OP.

Comment: I'm not agreeing with the policy, just reiterating what it is. These flags should be used for answers that are not ***an*** answer, if the answer is actually a question or anything else that is not ***an*** answer, use this flag, otherwise downvote and move on.

Comment: @Tiny [even questions can be answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300987/should-we-avoid-rhetorical-questions-in-answers). Anyway let's leave it at that I don't agree with how you interpret the rules.

Comment: Under certain circumstances (which I don't agree with) yes, but it still applies, if an answer is actually asking a question (not rhetorically) then it would be a good use of a NaA flag, because it isn't an answer. From the page I linked previous "*Do not use this flag when ... You have to consider the question, other answers, or even the comments on the answer itself in order to determine if an answer is not-an-answer*". If it is possibly an answer to a question then it is an answer. For example, if I asked an SQL question who's resulting answer would be that snippet.

Comment: It is not true that you can't flag for "Not an answer" if an answer potentially answers _any_ question.

Comment: Any question conceivably asked on this site. The best option would be to custom flag "This answer is a joke" because it is *an* answer, but it is a joke and jokes are not allowed as answers.

Comment: That's not how this site works. You post an answer under a question, and your answer has to be an attempt to answer the question you post it to. From [Help Center -> Answering -> How do I write a good answer?, Answer the question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): _"Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead""_.

Comment: I understand that you may disagree with the policy, but the policy is what it is. Previous guidance has been given to just use a custom flag if the answer does not answer the question directly. If the mod has to look at the question to determine that the answer does not answer *the* question then NaA is not appropriate. It should only be used when you can tell from the answer itself that it could not conceivably answer a question on this site. See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286270/4639281

Comment: The policy about NaA as recently expressed is asinine and frankly inconsistent with other mod-expressed policies. Disagreeing with it and acting contrary to it are entirely sensible actions.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Your opinion of the policy does not change the policy. If you wish to change the policy then you should post a feature request. Acting contrary to the policy does not help any situation, it will only get you flag banned.

Comment: @Tiny this post we're talking about clearly is a joke, cleverly disguised as valid code. That makes that the mod has to pay more effort when reading it when it's flagged, but it is not an answer.

Comment: It is an answer though. It is a bad one, it is a joke, but it is an answer. If it is a bad answer, vote it down. If it is a joke, use a custom flag. But it is an answer so the NaA flag is wrong. I could conceivably ask a question who's answer would be that snippet of code, so it is an answer.

Comment: *Your opinion of the policy does not change the policy.* Heh, the EU and Stack Exchange have something in common after all. I only hope the latter will survive it better than the former.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi If you want to change it, I would agree with you, then post a feature request and use the correct channels to change the policy. If enough people show that they want this using the correct channels then it will most likely eventually be changed, until then the policy is what it is and being a rebel solves nothing.

Comment: @Tiny heh, seems you're right in the letter of the law. Thanks, I didn't know the "Not an answer" flag was that delicate. Answer updated.

Comment: I've been bitten by it before, that's how I know. Who knows, if the moderators start getting boat loads of custom flags then things might change.

Comment: @Tiny, it's true I couldn't find any feature requests about this (at first glance), but there are hordes of shot down discussions about our current interpretation of the NAA flag (which, as I previously stated somewhere, does not always look consistent from one moderator to another). Surely opening a feature request instead of a discussion wouldn't prevent such a question to suffer the same fate. The community seems to have made its collective mind here.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I would most definitely support such a request (as I'm sure countless others will) but for all of those discussions the answer is the current policy, which seems to be contrary to popular belief/opinion.

Comment: There may not be a formal feature req post, @TinyGiant, but it's been raised enough (most notably by MichaelT, who's removed his SO account, though some of the posts are on Meta.SE) that I'm content with everyone just keeping on doing what they think is right and  meeting somewhere in the middle. I think there might even be a Q post that flat out says "change this", but I'm not going to be able to find it right now on my phone.

Comment: @Josh, the closest thing I could find (not on my phone, where I crawl to six words/minute when I'm lucky) was [evidence our current  interpretation of NAA was already around back in 2011](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115627/please-provide-a-flag-option-clearly-designed-for-gibberish-contentless-posts) (see the first few comments) and [suspicion the whole thing may come from initial abuse of spam flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96264/164403). As far as I can tell, there always has been a category of posts we wanted to remove as, say, *complete crap*, without being able to.

Comment: @JoshCaswell [What constitutes an answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277048/839601)

Comment: ...and there is of course my favorite, [Why was this 'not an answer' flag declined?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268369/839601) where everyone supporting decline suggests to turn off reading comprehension