# Flag for "not an answer" declined

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569473/sql-goto-statement-using-variable-label/569529#569529) as not an answer for moderator attention.

But it was declined as:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Surely if it's not an answer then the flag could be helpful?

Comment: Are you not aware answers can be worded in the form of a question?  Should I not illustrate this via a comment?  Have you not learned that it's not really that important to bother a moderator over seven year old content?  [Are we not men?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d43gKl9xIME)

Comment: Relevant: [*Should we avoid rhetorical questions in answers?*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300987/2751851)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is:

> not tested but does exec("goto "+@label) work ?

Based on this, we can reword it in:

> try this:
>
> ```
> exec("goto "+@label)
> ```

It is surely a bad answer, but it is an answer* [according to meta consensus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/2441442):

> Any post that attempts to answer the question, however badly is still
>   an answer. You can downvote such posts to signal that the answer is a
>   bad answer, but it is still an answer.

<sub>*Personaly I would agree with you</sub>

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now...I was reading it as a question, when in fact it's just a poorly written answer

Comment: I wouldn't mind down voting an answer if it didn't remove a reputation point for doing so

Comment: @MarkO'Sullivan You might be interessted in [this FR](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339034/summary-of-downvoted-answers-which-have-changed-and-are-not-deleted).

Comment: I like that idea +1 from me