# Questions In Answers Revisited

Tags: discussion

After asking for some guidance into why a flag I had raised on what I considered a suspect answer was declined, I was directed to this: [Should we avoid rhetorical questions in answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300987/should-we-avoid-rhetorical-questions-in-answers)

I understand the reasoning that the OP was trying to convey with respect to the post of his that had been deleted. I also understand that this became sort of a precedent for later moderator action, in that answers containing rhetorical questions were to be allowed.

My question is this: Should this same standard apply to an answer that consists of ONLY a question to the asker, or to non-rhetorical questions? I hold that a blanket acceptance of questions as answers errs too far on the side of leniency.

EDIT: It appears I was not able to provide a clear enough abstract of the situation I thought needed discussion and perhaps correction. Here is the answer that spawn my flag and subsequently this question: [C++ Else statement in Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841828/c-else-statement-in-exception-handling/41841850#41841850)

For the sake of full disclosure, yes I answered the question, but did so after I flagged this answer.

Comment: Can a question contain an answer?

Comment: @CodeCaster I am not certain how that relates to my question, unless it is to point out I provided my own answer, but I'd think that questions on SO need at least something that requires an answer, even if it is confirmation of what the asker already believes to be the case.

Comment: No, it was a rhetorical question meant to answer your question. Read it as _"Can an answer containing a question still be an answer?"_. Of course _"Are you sure you want to be doing this?"_ is not an answer to the question and should be flagged as such. In other words: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask that hasn't been answered in the question you link to. Can you link to an answer where you wondered this?

Comment: @CodeCaster No, but "Are you sure you want to be doing this?" followed by reasons they shouldn't be is an absolutely acceptable answer.  For example "How do I send someone their password via email?"  "Are you sure you want to do that?  Its plain text and can be captured.  Also, you probably shouldn't know their password to begin with, you should be hashing it".

Comment: @Gabe my point exactly (see also my answer to the linked question), hence my asking for an example.

Comment: Having a "blanket standard" for this type of thing is the definition of absurd. Look at the answer, evaluate it in context—does it answer the question? Is it useful? Should we keep it around? Use your brain.

Comment: @CodeCaster We are not merely seeking answers. We are looking for good answers. An answer that contains questions in not the same as an answer that consists of a single question with nothing more.

Comment: I'm not denying that, @MikelF. Perhaps check my profile for what causes I've been advocating here on Meta. My point is that the burden of proof here is on **you**. I'm asking why you're asking this question.

Comment: @MikelF These cases are trivial to evaluate.  Would re-phrasing the question at a statement make it an answer?  If so, it's clearly an answer.  If not, or if it's not possible to meaningfully translate the question into a statement, then it's Not An Answer.  The grammatical form of the answer has no real bearing on whether or not it's an answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster Can a comment contain a question that is an answer to an answer that is a question contained in a comment?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I don't know, I encountered a stack overflow trying to parse your comment.

Comment: @CodeCaster http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666282/work-around-a-stackoverflowexception

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should we avoid rhetorical questions in answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300987/should-we-avoid-rhetorical-questions-in-answers)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rhetorical questions as such are merely a stylistic choice, there's nothing wrong with having *a* rhetorical question in *an* answer. Now, what if the answer *solely* consists of a rhetorical question? Then it's *probably* a VLQ answer.

I can certainly imagine situations in which a masterful use of a rhetorical question points out the solution to a problem. However, it probably cannot do more than *point it out*, it's hard to *spell out* a solution using a rhetorical question. And we prefer answers to be as plain and unambiguous as possible, so a single rhetorical question may not fulfil that goal for all future visitors.

I think the comments above make my case:

> Can a question contain an answer? – CodeCaster

> @CodeCaster I am not certain how that relates to my question ... – Mikel F

Looks like that wasn't exactly an unambiguous answer. Rhetorical questions can be quite subtle to comprehend, and as was the case in the [original question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300987/should-we-avoid-rhetorical-questions-in-answers), they'll probably be misunderstood by reviewers.

Answer (score 6):

If question in the answer actually answers the question it is an answer. Feel free to edit and reword to remove rhetorical question part so there is no confusion whether it is an answer or a misguided question.

If question is the answer is merely request for more information - downvote/flag as not an answer.

Anything in between - probably deserves downvote, consider adding comment to clarify intent.

Comment: Is there a sentence missing after "so" in the first paragraph (eg. "so that [...]")?

Comment: @duplode thanks. I don't know why I've added "so", but since it there I've added reason for edit.

Answer (score 5):

Alright, the answer in case:

> Why not just put it at the end of the try block?

Is not a good answer. I can only imagine it being upvoted eleven (!) times by *people who already know what doing so does*.

The answer does not explain what "putting it at the end of the try block" does, so it is not a good answer.

All you can do is downvote it though, because this can't be stressed enough: it is *an* answer.

Comment: I sense that there have been wars waged in the past over things like this prior to my arrival here.

Comment: Correct. Just do a search for "not an answer flag rejected".

Answer (score 0):

Do we really need a blanket statement regarding this?

Why not just evaluate each answer based on its individual merit?

If a solution is phrased as a rhetorical question, does that preclude it from being a solution?

Comment: The guidance I was given was that the post referenced above about rhetorical questions in answers now drove moderator action with respect to how they responded to NAA flags. Whether or not there IS a blanket policy, the perception of those I queried is that there is.

Comment: And the point of my post is that such a policy allows answers that it should not. Which seems to be what you are saying.

Comment: That does not change the fact that we don't need a blanket statement regarding this, we should evaluate each answer based on its individual merit, and phrasing a solution as a rhetorical question does not preclude it from being a solution. Just because something contains a question mark does not mean that it is Not an Answer. The answer you referenced is in fact an answer, and it does not have severe content or formatting problems, so it should not have been flagged. You should downvote and delete vote such content if you think it is not useful

Comment: And I am not saying that we need a blanket statement. I am saying that the perception is that we have one.

Comment: We don't have one, you just flagged a valid answer as not an answer and got your flag declined. I regularly flag answers that are actually questions, and not just solutions phrased as rhetorical questions, I don't recall having such a flag declined.