# Is it ok to ask non-rhetorical (clarification) questions in the answer?

Tags: discussion

Let say I've posted the answer. Good answer (not off-topic at least).

Is it ok to ask questions in my answer at the end?

> You do can do it this way, or this way.
>
> Have you set it up like this? What exactly did you try?

I couldn't find duplicate, only discussions about [rhetorical questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342277/1997232). But in my case those questions are not rhetorical.

In reality it wasn't my answer, nor my questions at the end of it. I guess the intent is to continue adding information into the answer or helping in comments under the answer.

Is it ok?

What should I do with such answers?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**No, it is not OK to post additional questions in an answer.**

The site follows a strict question/answer paradigm. If someone is legitimately asking follow-up questions to the poster of the question after having written an answer, then they are looking to enter a rabbit hole or ping-pong that the site was *specifically designed to avoid*. Visitors don't want yet another experience of reading pages of comments and discussions to find a solution, and this kind of behaviour pretty much incentivises this experience.

Should the user need something about the question clarified, one should leave a comment before an answer is even made. Otherwise, the risk of posting something that does not quite align with the OP's original intent is higher.

Should you find an answer which does this, evaluate whether there is value in the post without the follow-up question. If there isn't, then it's not an answer and should be flagged as such. Otherwise, consider removing the question, and voting accordingly.

---

Note that even rhethorical questions are also likely to trick people into thinking that the post is *Not an Answer*, which does not always apply. It is often best to avoid sentences with question marks in a way that could be misinterpreted.

Comment: Comments are fifth-class citizens.  I understand their use for clarification, but I loathe using them, even to state this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey TBF in that case I wouldn't bother commenting nor answering. I find it more frustrating to post an answer that deviates from what the OP had in mind than to post a comment with similar risks of beginning a discussion.

Comment: There's a bigger picture here.  The way comments are moderated nowadays is so unreliable that you can't depend on them to accomplish anything meaningful.  If Stack Exchange's intention is to support the kind of questions that require extensive clarification (and there every indication [that's what they want](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399848/102937)), it's going to take more than merely enforcing a "strict question/answer paradigm."

Comment: Conversely, a question should actually have a question in it (i.e. a sentence starting with "how/what/why/where" and ending with "?"). An answer should have zero sentences ending with a "?" character, even if it's purely rhetorical. Rhetorical questions ("Would you want your application to crash on this input?") can be rephrased to be non-rhetorical ("You wouldn't want your application to crash on this input") which improves clarity as a side effect. Rare exceptions that prove the rule may apply!

Answer (score 8):

I think it's fine to treat these comments as any other piece of "noise" on a post, like salutations.

If it's not really part of the answer and one is sure these "questions" do not really convey additional meaning that could be edited in a clearer manner; I believe it's fine to edit them out.

In any case, these questions can make more evident problems with the original question these posts are supposed to answer. Sometimes the most effective way of dealing this these situations is voting to close the question that caused the problem to arise in the first place.